Select item inside a react-select dropdown list in Selenium with Java
I have this element, where it has this:
aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--option-3" and when I click the menu dropdown shows 4 options (option-0, option-1, option-2, and the one I need to click --option-3), but I can't select this -option-3
This is the code I have when I am inspecting and I am using Java and Selenium
<div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"> ==$0
    <input id="buscaPontoVendaLoginSelect" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--**option-3**" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="react-select-2--list" role="combobox" value style="box-sizing: content-box; with: 5px;">

How can I catch this element?
I am trying to click the option 3 using java+selenium

You should include the markup of the DOM when this menu is open.  (right-click in the browser, choose "Inspect", copy/paste the relevant markup.)  Also include the code you've tried.

If that's the DOM while the dropdown is open, it would be something like XPATH of //input[@aria-activedescendant='react-select-2--option-3']... or //input[contains(@aria-activedescendant, 'option-3')]
